# Pausing and starting a loop

Tags: go

when a client connects to the server I am upgrading their connection to a websocket connection and sending them back data from a large json file. This works fine, however, when the user wants to stop, I receive the command and want to `pause` the stream of data and then when they want to `resume` the data is continued to be sent. I can't seem to latter two options to work. I have looked at channels but can't quiet seem to get how to do it. what I have is something like this

```golang
func foo() {
    switch cmd {
    case "play":
      for _, data := range arr {
         // send data
      }
    case "stop":
    case "resume":
}
```

there are a couple things that I have tried but can't really get it the way that I want, one of them being channels, which I can't seem to get working the way that I want and the other is using a `break` of the the labeled loop, which isn't working because of scope:

```golang
func foo() {
    var lastIndex := 0

    switch cmd {
    case "play":
    Loop: // <-- not used
      for i, data := range arr {
         lastIndex = i
         // send data
      }
    case "stop":
      break Loop // <-- error Loop not defined
    case "resume":
    // start to send the data back from lastIndex
}
```

am I on the right track above? Are channels better for this? Or is there a better way to do this?
[here is an example](https://play.golang.org/p/iS1bQf2-bTU)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, that `switch` on a channel should be a `select` command, and it has a slightly different syntax, as shown in the examples below.

Second, the key issue with trying to interrupt a loop in this fashion is that the `for` loop is the thing that needs to be interrupted.  Your code does not do that--the program will reach the `for i, data := range arr {}` block and loop over `arr` until it reaches the end, after which it will break out of the `case` condition.

If you want to use channels to interrupt the `for` loop, you have to read the channel within the loop itself, like this:

```
func foo(cmd chan string) {
    // define arr
    // begin loop over arr first
    for i, data := range arr {
        // check for a command within the loop
        select {
        case s := <-cmd:
            // if cmd contains a value switch on that
            switch s {
            case "stop":
                // do whatever
            case "resume":
                // do whatever
            default:
                // handle the case where the command is unrecognized
            }
        default:
            // there is no command, so continue the loop as normal
        }
    }
    return
}
```

Note that I do not include a "play" command. The default behavior of the loop should be to continue looping, and checking the channel for the value "play" would mean something would have to push that to the channel for every iteration of this loop to complete.

Check [this playground code](https://play.golang.org/p/zTCCvEVbavi) for a simple example of this in action.

If you want to pause and resume the loop, treat the command sent on the channel as a transition of a finite state machine and act accordingly:

```
func foo(cmd chan string) {
    state := "play"
    for i, data := range arr {
        // check for a command within the loop,
        // but use different logic if paused to avoid a busyloop
        if state == "pause" {
            // keep reading cmd until a valid command is received
LOOP:
            for s := range cmd {
                switch s {
                case "stop":
                    return
                case "resume":
                    state = "play"
                    break LOOP
                default:
                    // deal with unrecognized command
                }
            }
            // if the channel closes while still in the "pause" state,
            // deal with that here
            if state == "pause" {
                return
            }
        }
        // resume normal operation
        select {
        case state = <-cmd:
            // if cmd contains a value switch on that
            switch state {
            case "stop":
                return
            case "pause":
                // continue the loop, but pause next time around
            default:
                // handle the case where the command is unrecognized
            }
        default:
            // there is no command, so continue the loop as normal
        }
    }
    return
}
```

Check [this playground code](https://play.golang.org/p/MHPnI1Kwhf6) for an example of this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is pretty simple, since you need to check for the Stop signal from client, start a goroutine and listening for client cmd, push the cmd to cmdCh (for example) and then in the main thread every time you sending the data down to websocket check for cmd:

```
for i, data := range arr {
     lastIndex = i
     select {
         case cmd := <-cmdCh:
              switch (cmd) {
                  case "Stop":
                      return
                  default:
                      // send data
              }
         default:
             // send data
     }
 }
```

Comment: I had something like that before, but, it wasn't working as it was supposed to. I think maybe I was over complicating things? I'll give it a look again after a break because I've been staring at the same block for a while now